# "Out of Memory" while populating TreeView

Tags: c#, windows

I am facing "Out of Memory" issue when I am populating TreeView hierarchy using XML. Our XML structure is very complex and it is not in fix format. There are multiple level of child nodes. I am using recursion to iterate XML and populate TreeView structure. I tried to call GC.Collect.   to clear memory but still it is throwing same error.
I am using C# of .NET framework 3.5 for development.

I will appreciate if you can help me to find solution for this.

I'm providing the Code, Which I'm using for populating the treeview, below

```
private void addTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode, TreeNode treeNode)
{
    string attribute = "";

    treeView1.ImageList = imageList1;
    treeViewResponse.ImageList = imageList1;
    XmlNode xNode;
    TreeNode tNode;
    XmlNodeList xNodeList;
    foo.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
    namespaces1 = foo.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
    if (xmlNode.HasChildNodes)
    {

        treeNode.ImageIndex = 0;
        treeNode.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
        xNodeList = xmlNode.ChildNodes;
        for (int x = 0; x <= xNodeList.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            xNode = xmlNode.ChildNodes[x];
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
            tNode = treeNode.Nodes[x];
            //treeNode.Nodes[x].ImageIndex = -1;
            addTreeNode(xNode, tNode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        treeNode.ImageIndex = 1;
        treeNode.NodeFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        treeNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
        treeNode.Text = xmlNode.OuterXml.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use less memory. For example, instead of creating a `new Font` for each node, just create one font and reuse it. There is a limit of 10,000 graphics objects per process, and a font counts as a graphics object.

Comment: Just ran into this problem. RaymondChen and @Steven Knauber's answers worked for me, but in case someone is interested I found [this thread with more in depth discussion](http://forum.memprofiler.com/viewtopic.php?t=1254) (apparently this problem has existed at least since .NET 2.0!)

Answer (score 5):

As Raymond suggested, you should construct the font one time and reuse it.  I have noticed that even if you do this, changing node fonts immediately causes a redraw of the control which can cause TreeView to construct internal fonts in addition to the one you provided it.  I have seen cases where this can cause the font handle usage to go up very fast such that the garbage collector does not free them fast enough.  I think this is a bug in TreeView that is not very repeatable but will happen sometimes.  A way to protect yourself against Treeview using all your application's GDI handles is to wrap a set of node adds or font changes in TreeView.BeginUpdate() and TreeView.EndUpdate() calls.

```
m_treeView.BeginUpdate();
try
{
    // TreeNode adds changes here
}
finally
{
    m_treeView.EndUpdate();
}
```

This will result in only one redraw even though you added or changed multiple nodes.

Steve

Comment: Similar "temporary memory gobbling" happens when a UI framework attempts to animate massive changes to your database model... for this reason, I've had to turn off all animations when I know a massive change is occurring.